# Searching in text file in c#?

Tags: c#, binaryfiles

i am trying to search within a text file written with `BinaryWriter` and have to input the `id`

i want to search in `TextBox` and then search for it But the problem is that  i have to enter the same order of id to search for 
**for example** suppose that  i have 3 records with id 1,2,3
if i enter 1 it will show it's data in text box 
then if i enter 3 it will show it's data in text box 
but when i enter 2 it will show the exception (`Unable to read beyond the end of the stream`)

This is my code to search in text file and display the rest of data in text boxes in form (*Record Size = 35*)

```
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open("D:\\File.txt", 
      FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        int num_records = (int)br.BaseStream.Length / Class1.rec_size;

        int x = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < num_records; i++)
        {
            br.BaseStream.Seek(Class1.count, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            if (int.Parse(br.ReadString()) == x)
            {
                // textBox2.Text = int.Parse(br.ReadString()).ToString();
                textBox3.Text = br.ReadString();
                textBox4.Text = br.ReadString();
                textBox5.Text = int.Parse(br.ReadString()).ToString();
                textBox6.Text = br.ReadString();


                break;
            }

            Class1.count += Class1.rec_size;
        }

        br.Close();
    }
```

Comment: How big is your file?

Comment: this is the text file :00001 1111     1111       1111100002 1111     1111       1111100003 1111     1111       11111

Comment: The total record size is 107 each record is 35

Comment: I think you may need to show us exactly how and where these records are being called to be read, as well as a better example. Clearly it has something to do with the way you are reading the stream, e.g, `br.ReadString();` continuously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forget to reset your Class1.Count.

In your codeline:
        `br.BaseStream.Seek(Class1.count, SeekOrigin.Begin);`
You have an offset of Class1.Count. Since at the end of each record you add to the offset `Class1.count += Class1.rec_size;` you will only search the stream in upward direction, that is why it succeeds in an ordered search.

You need to reset this counter for each search to start at the beginning of the stream again.